# sql left join get matched records with left join

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

how to get only matching records with left join based on a column from right table if right table column value is specified.

eg.

```
SELECT A.* FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.COLUMN_1 = B.COLUMN_1 and B.COLUMN_1 IN (1,2)

-- in above case i want to get only matching records with B.COLUMN_1 is 1 or 2.
```

if B.COLUMN_1 is not specified, i need to get all records from left table.

Comment: I don't understand the requirement. Can you post some sample data and the result you're trying to get?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    A.* 
FROM 
    A 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        B.* 
    FROM 
        B 
    WHERE 
        B.COLUMN_1 IN (1,2)
) BB ON A.COLUMN_1 = BB.COLUMN_1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a `UNION` of both form to get all data like

```
SELECT A.* 
FROM A 
LEFT JOIN B 
ON A.COLUMN_1 = B.COLUMN_1 
and B.COLUMN_1 IN (1,2)

UNION

SELECT A.* 
FROM A 
JOIN B ON A.COLUMN_1 = B.COLUMN_1 
and B.COLUMN_1 IN (1,2)
```